# Raspbian space disk by default

Tags: command-line, raspberry-pi, disk-space, raspbian

I'm doing my first steps with Raspberry Pi (3B+), and I'm not sure about my SD card. I already have a 8 GB, but my question is :

Is a 8GB SD card enough to install Raspbian and few packages such as disk utility tools, scripting tools and is there a big difference if I don't install any X server ?

Thank you all.

gZen0n

Comment: I guess that 8GB is more than enough. I do not have any experience with a Raspberry-Pi, but even on a Desktop PC 8GB is enough for a Linux-based OS.

Answer (score 1):

8GB is definitely enough, that should leave about 2-3 GB free space if you use "Raspbian with Desktop" image.

If you use "raspbian lite" image, you will have about 5GB free space left.